# Set a String to a value and use it later

Tags: c, arrays, loops, pointers

```
char * programName = tokens_get_token(tokens, 0);

    if (access(programName, F_OK) != 0){
      /*name not okay, set programName to correct path-name*/
      char * fullpath = getenv("PATH");
      /*/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:*/
      for (char * p = strtok(fullpath, ":"); p!= NULL; p = strtok(NULL, ":")){
        char * concatPath = malloc(strlen(programName) +strlen(p) + 2);
        strcpy(concatPath, p);
        strcat(concatPath, "/");
        strcat(concatPath, programName);
        printf("%s\n", concatPath);
        bool toBreak = false;
        if (access(concatPath, F_OK) == 0){
          /*can a string be reset like this? */
          programName = concatPath;


           HERE



          toBreak = true;
        }
        free(concatPath);
        if (toBreak){
          break;
        }
      }
    }
    printf("%s%s\n", programName, "is programName");
    execv(programName, listOfArgs);
```

When I print programName at HERE, it is indeed concatPath. However, when I actually want to use it in the very last line of the code attached, programName becomes empty. Note that ProgramName is defined in the first line, outside the if loop.

Why is this **and how can I fix it**?

(I thought the problem is I can't reset the string programName like that but why, then, is programName successfully set to the new value concatPath at HERE, when I print it there? Furthermore, why does programName forget its value altogether when I want to use it it the last line?)

Comment: You are using 'free' on concatPath,
so ProgramName which points at it will now hold free memory. 

In that case, the data which it points to is unknown.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Reason:

Here you assign it to be a value you just allocated:

```
 programName = concatPath;
```

Here you free the allocated value

```
 free(concatPath);
```

Obviously `programName` from this point will point to a freed piece of memory.

How to fix it:

1. use a separate variable
2. allocate it to hold the correct length
3. `strcpy` into it, because pointer assignment does not copy the  strings.
4. Use it
5. Free it.